# Play framework 2.3.x Running without console

Tags: ssh, playframework, console, server, playframework-2.3

I am in need to run a play through **ssh** on server.

Problem is that after I quit **ssh**, play console is going down and server is being killed.

Are there any ways to `start play 2.3.x` without console ,so the program can run after I disconnect from **ssh**??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nohup` for this, i.e. (when using with *dist* package):

```
nohup /path/to/your/app/bin/yourapp &
```

instead of just

```
./yourapp
```

[@see: its description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup)